# Jacobian using in Maple

Tags: maple

How can I use the Jacobian written below as function from (x, y) ?

```
g := (x, y) -> x - y
u := (x, y) -> x^2 + y^2

J := jacobian([g(x, y), u(x, y)], [x, y]);
```

My idea was to make funcion like this

```
Jf := (u, v) -> subs(x = u, y = v, J(x, y))
```

but it returns ugly matrix with brakets inside.

P. S. I use Maple 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linalg package (which exports the `jacobian` command) and lowercase `matrix` are deprecated. Use LinearAlgebra and Matrix instead, and `VectorCalculus:-Jacobian`.

Also, note the use of `unapply`.

```
restart:

g := (x, y) -> x - y:

u := (x, y) -> x^2 + y^2:

J:=VectorCalculus:-Jacobian([g(x,y),u(x,y)],[x,y]);

                                [ 1     -1 ]
                           J := [          ]
                                [2 x    2 y]

Jf:=unapply(J,[x,y]):

Jf(1,1);

                               [1    -1]
                               [       ]
                               [2     2]

Jf(s,t);
                             [ 1     -1 ]
                             [          ]
                             [2 s    2 t]
```

Comment: I would add that the result of the unapply is nasty to look at, so just suppress the output of that, like you did.

Comment: That is exactly what I searched for! Thanks)